# Calculate sum of values in lists with same class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find the sum of values. I've put my code so far below.

The HTML

```
<ul class='share'>
    <li class='share-btn'>
        <a class="total"></a>
    </li>
    <li class='share-btn' data-service="facebook">
        <a class="count"></a>
    </li>
    <li class='share-btn' data-service="twitter">
        <a class="count"></a>
    </li>
    <li class='share-btn' data-service="google">
        <a class="count"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var shareUrl = "http://www.google.com";
    $.getJSON('http://count.donreach.com/?url=' + encodeURIComponent(shareUrl) + "&callback=?", function (data) {
        var shares = data.shares;
        $(".count").each(function (index, el) {
            var service = $(el).parents(".share-btn").attr("data-service");
            var count = shares[service]; 
            $(el).text(count);
        });
    });
});
```

How to get total of values in list with same class ("count"), and put the result at "total".

Comment: do you want sum of count to total ?

Comment: Sum up the totals in the loop, then place that total in the element after the loop. `var total = 0; $('.count').each(function (idx, el) { .... total += count; }); $('.total').text(total);`

Comment: Exactly what values are you talking about?

Comment: what data is comming in `data.shares`?

Comment: this case is solved, i'm using script from @ChrisBaker :)

Answer (score 0):

This function will help you:

```
var total = 0;
$('.count').each(
    function(){
        total += parseInt($(this).text().trim());
    }
);
$('.total').html(total);
```